# Bed Graphics Glitch

Tags: prison-architect

[image]

This just started happening today, so I assume it has something to do with Update 7. When the Worker picked up the Bed from Storage, this happened. When I tried to get a screenshot, it disappeared. It popped up a few seconds later.

Is this just a bug, and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Does it actually get installed that way, or just while the worker is carrying it?

Comment: @TimS. It looks like it's just while being carried.

Comment: Looking at the materials.txt file there does not seem to be anything obviously off about it. No sprite scale at least. Do you have any mods on? If so, try turning them off, especially those adding graphics.

Comment: Nope, no mods. I have edited the save file a few times, but only the `Balance` value (bugged money).

Comment: Actually, I reproduced it in my save file. Hrmm... what did they do...

Comment: I just experienced this same issue. For me, it happened when I had my Intake window open on the right side, and a workman carried a bed on-screen towards a new jail cell. Once I closed the Intake window, seconds later the bed went back to normal size and shape. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

After comparing the old and the new game files, this issue was likely introduced in the actual executable. No changes were made to the "Bed" sprite or object, nor the "Box" sprite or object between update 6 and 7. As such, we can't mod the game to fix the bug.

I have filed [bug #10863](http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=10863) with Introversion. The actual issue seems to be with any object that has a height, that is carried, and is rotated 45 degrees to the left.

Comment: Glad to hear this - I recently also had this again with a regular door, so this definitely corroborates what you mentioned.